# @SpyBean and Mockito.any() during verify

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, mockito, integration-testing, springmockito

I'm experiencing following problem. I've got a spring boot test, where I inject and spy the `mongoDbChannel` bean. Then I try to start the normal workflow and verify if the method `send` is called on the bean.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MongoAsBackupConfig.class},
        properties = {},
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
public class MongoAsBackupConfigTest {
    @SpyBean(name = "mongoDbChannel")
    private QueueChannel mongoDbChannel;

    @Autowired
    private DirectChannel mongoDbWithFailoverChannel;

    @DirtiesContext
    @Test
    public void shouldUseFallbackForFullQueue() throws InterruptedException {
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, BACKUP_QUEUE_CAPACITY + OVERFILLING_CLICK_COUNT).forEach(someNumber ->
            mongoDbWithFailoverChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(createPayload(someNumber)).build()));
        verify(mongoDbChannel, times(BACKUP_QUEUE_CAPACITY)).send(Mockito.any());
    }
}
```

As a result, I get the error message that `any` doesn't match to the concrete parameter value. However normally `any` means any value of param. What went wrong here?

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
mongoDbChannel.send(
    <any>
);
-> at MongoAsBackupConfigTest.shouldUseFallbackForFullQueue(MongoAsBackupConfigTest.java:67)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
mongoDbChannel.send(
    GenericMessage [payload=Click(...), headers={id=0eaa2317-b1b5-604d-65c5-78da521cd585, timestamp=1509085945379}],
    10
);
-> at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
```

EDITED:
I'm using java 8. And I tried to use `any(GenericMessage.class)`, `any(Message.class)` but it was the same effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using java 8 which means that when using `Mockito.any()`, the compiler will infer the type that has to be used based on the parameter type in the signature of `send` method.

That seems to be `Message` based on the method definition : `send(Message<?> message)`

What is actually passed is an instance of `GenericMessage`.

As I assume `GenericMessage` extends `Message`, then you can write your `verify` as follows:

```
verify(mongoDbChannel, times(BACKUP_QUEUE_CAPACITY))
   .send(Mockito.any(GenericMessage.class));
```

**Update**

There also seems to be an overloaded method `send(Message<?> message, long timeout)`. Maybe this version gets called instead of the single arg one..

Comment: yes it's java 8. Unfortunatelly you proposal doesn't work as well with the same error message. I tried also any(Message.class).

Comment: yes, it does! It's visible in the error message `send(
    GenericMessage [],
    10
);` It works now, thnx.